# User Follower model on Django. Cannot use add() on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model. Use accounts.Contact's Manager instead

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-users

I am new to Django, Please forgive any silly mistakes in code or logic,

**Intro:** I am trying to create a user follower model in Django. Where users can follow and unfollow other users on the sites

**Error:**  I have made the `models` for my follow/unfollow I have also made the `views` I am getting this error

```
AttributeError at /accounts/admin/follow/
Cannot use add() on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model. Use accounts.Contact's Manager instead.
```

The `obj.followers.add(user)` is highlighted in the traceback as the origin of the error

Below are my **models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('accounts:profile', kwargs={'username': self.user.username})

class Contact(models.Model):
    user_from = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='suppporter')
    user_to = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='leader')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} follows {}'.format(self.user_from, self.user_to)


User.add_to_class('following',
                  models.ManyToManyField('self', through=Contact, related_name='followers', symmetrical=False))
```

I think the models.py may be good. The fault I believe is in my views. 
Below is my **view.py**

```
class FollowToggle(LoginRequiredMixin, RedirectView):

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        username = self.kwargs.get('username')
        print(username + " This is the user who will be followed") # This prints correct
        profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user__username=username)
        print(profile) # This prints correct
        obj = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
        print(obj) # This prints correct
        url_ = profile.get_absolute_url()
        print(url_) # This prints correct
        user = self.request.user
        print(user) # This prints correct
        if user.is_authenticated():
            if user in obj.followers.all(): # I know this is the source of the error.
                obj.followers.remove(user)
            else:
                obj.followers.add(user)
        return url_
```

Below are the **Urls.py** just in case

```
url(r'^(?P<username>[-\w]+)/follow/$', views.FollowToggle.as_view(), name='follow'),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `add` and `remove` method for manytomany relation defined through third model. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships):

> Unlike normal many-to-many fields, you can’t use add(), create(), or set() to create relationships

Instead you should use `Contact` manager:

```
if user.is_authenticated():
    if user in obj.followers.all(): # I know this is the source of the error.
        Contact.objects.filter(user_to=obj, user_from=user).delete()
    else:
        Contact.objects.create(user_to=obj, user_from=user)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Django 2.2 you can use `add`, `remove` and `set` methods ([Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships))

> You can also use add(), create(), or set() to create relationships, as long as your specify through_defaults for any required fields